# How to interact with a Qt application widget from another Qt app?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to get the text of a Qtextedit from an application written in QT (a chat messenger) using another QT app that i am writing code. After using Ranorex for UI automation test, I got the widget name and its properties. I would like to ask how I could interact with it? Just give me some guidelines and I will study . Thank you ~

Comment: There's no easy way to do it aumatically; You'll need to use some kind of IPC (inter-process communications) mechanism to send messages from one app to the other that contains the data you need to transfer.  You could use Qt's networking APIs for this purpose, or some other communications mechanism like shared memory or D-Bus or named pipes or etc.

Comment: I would also suggest to modify the source code of *both* applications. I am assuming the chat messenger is some free software (or an open source one).Then you might use clipboard related things, or networking API, ...

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will study those approaches ~

Comment: I think Ranorex does not use IPC, but hooks to the Qt dlls in some way to grab the information about the widgets.